# Return Android dialog view?

Tags: android, dialog

I am using this code to create a custom dialog. It is fine, but for some reason, I want to return or get the dialog view. This is the reason: I want to animate the dialog to achieve an expand/collapse feature inside the dialog, and for that I need to have the view for the dialog.

```
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),
                    R.style.CustomDialog);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_enter_name);


            dialog.setTitle("Hello");


            Button dialogButtonOK = (Button) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            Button dialogButtonCancel = (Button) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonCancel);
            nameField = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nameField);
            lastNameField = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.familyField);

            //And some code for OK/Cancel button.
```

This is the class that i am going to use to animate the dialog. As you see it requires a View.

```
    public class HeightAnimation extends Animation {
    protected final int originalHeight;
    protected final View view;
    protected float perValue;

    public HeightAnimation(View view, int fromHeight, int toHeight) {
        this.view = view;
        this.originalHeight = fromHeight;
        this.perValue = (toHeight - fromHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
            Transformation t) {
        view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (originalHeight + perValue
                * interpolatedTime);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is how i would use the class above:

```
                HeightAnimation heightAnim = new HeightAnimation(dialogview, 100, 400);
            heightAnim.setDuration(1000);
            dialogview.startAnimation(heightAnim);
```

The dialogview I used above should be the view for the Dialog. But i don't know how to get that?

Edit: I just found out how to do this:

```
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),
                    R.style.CustomDialog);
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            final View dialogview = factory.inflate(
                    R.layout.dialog_enter_name, null);


            dialog.setContentView(dialogview);
```